# Android app settings: why bother using PreferenceFragment if it's not supported before API 11?

Tags: android, android-preferences

PreferenceFragment is supported for implementing application preferences beginning with API 11 (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment). Prior to API 11, PreferenceActivity was used.

I have seen people struggle to implement PreferenceActivity for devices running older APIs while using PreferenceFragment for devices using newer APIs, in the same application.

Can anybody help me understand why we would bother to implement PreferenceFragment. Why not just continue to use PreferenceActivity? That is what I am doing in my application as of now.

Comment: Look http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html. That allows use Fragments (including PreferenceFragment) in older API's than 11

Comment: PreferenceFragment is not in the support library, and since it doesn't descend from the Fragment in the support library, it cannot be used in a FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 2):

I was doing what you were doing until I had an app that had so many preferences that I knew I needed to provide a two-pane layout, at least for tablet users. It looks way cleaner now, and on phones the left pane is full screen and behaves like a list of PreferenceScreens.

So I would say that it is worth using PreferenceFragments if you want to support two panes on tablets. But for most apps, there are not enough settings to justify using two panes at all, so it wouldn't be worth the effort to use PreferenceFragments. It definitely was a pain to get it working correctly and still support pre-v11. It's too bad PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment are not in the compatibility library...